# how to insert data in 2 mysql table at a time with a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql tables `tbl_account` and `tbl_user` . I want to add data into both tables using one form. I want to insert the following,

**`tbl_account` =** `account_id`, `account_name`, `secret_key`

**`tbl_user` =** `user_id`, `account_id`, `user_name`

What i'm doing is, inserting data in `tbl_account` then fetching `account_id` from that table and then inserting that same `account_id` in `tbl_user`. I'm fetching `account_id` through a `secret_key` which I pass in the form. Is this the right way or there is any simple way to do this. Please advice

Comment: How are you fetching the `account_id` after the insert?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic I'm getting it through secret_ket which is a random string. I update my question as well

Comment: This is the proper way UNLESS you are using `SELECT account_id FROM tbl_account ORDER BY account_id DESC LIMIT 1` to get the last key. This is a wrong way to get the last inserted id, because in time from your insert to your select query someone else might add a row and you would be getting wrong last id. Mysql has function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which you can use like `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the id. Your approach is also ok if `secret_key` is unique and indexed.

Comment: Yes the last ID i don't want to get because more then 1 user might add data the same time.

Comment: If your secret_key is unique than you are safe. Also, why do you need auto increment id if you are using unique secret key?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic yes i'm removing that. One question, I'm making secret with a combination of year+date+time+seconds+10 random characters to make sure its unique. Is it ok?

Comment: Can you use mysql `UUID()` or one of the php crypto functions or hashes, since it is generally good idea to use tested and proven functions which can guarantee uniqueness to larger degree.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic I will use account_id for a secret key but how can I use it as a primary key as its a random string of varchar type ?

Comment: Well if you use UUID() you will get fixed length string, which you can then use as a char(). It is more index efficient that way.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it would be easier to just put it in the 2 tables rather than inserting it in the first, reading it out, and then inserting again.

So i would do something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `tbl_account` (account_id, account_name) VALUES ('$account_id', '$account_name';");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (user_id , account_id, user_name) VALUES ('user_id', '$account_id', '$account_name';");
```

Comment: How would you know what `$account_id` is?

Comment: That would be the same value as $user_id wouldn't it?